# Is there a way to write ts modules as native code in the JavaScript data file when compiling?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

I want to divide an app in a TypeScript development environment into function files - so that each file contains only one function.
I would like to realise this with TS modules. In the compiled JavaScript file, however, these modules should not get imported at runtime, but compiled as native code.

For example, from this app.ts

```js
type ArbitraryAttribute = any //can refer to any value valid at runtime

declare interface App {
    get? (key: string): ArbitraryAttribute | void,
    set? (key: string, val: ArbitraryAttribute): void,
    helper?: AppHelper,
}

declare interface AppHelper {
    deepGetter? (key: string): ArbitraryAttribute | void,
    deepSetter? (key: string, val: ArbitraryAttribute): void,
}

import { get } from "./get";
import { set } from "./set";
import { helper } from "./helper/index";

const app:App = {
    get,
    set,
    helper,
}
```

this app.js is to be generated:

```js
var app = {
    get: function (key) {
        if (app.helper && app.helper.deepGetter) {
            return app.helper.deepGetter(key);
        };
    },
    set: function (key, val) {
        if (app.helper && app.helper.deepSetter) {
            app.helper.deepSetter(key, val);
        };
    },
    helper: {
        deepGetter: function (key) {
            // get anything
        },
        deepSetter: function (key, val) {
            // set anything
        },
    },
};
```

Neither in the TypeScript configuration nor in webpack have I found a solution for this.
This should be feasible, right? Does anyone know a solution or a library that solves this problem?

Comment: you need tsconfig outFile to compile everything into a single file

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "*compiled as native code*"

Comment: TypeScript doesn't do this afaik, but webpack is commonly used to **bundle** multiple modules into a single file.

Answer (score 0):

As @Dimava mentions, via tsconfig there is the possibility to merge a number of typescript files into a single js file, but the result for my aproach is really messy. The previosly postet js file will look like this:

```js
System.register("get", [], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var get;
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    return {
        setters: [],
        execute: function () {
            exports_1("get", get = function (key) {
                if (app.helper && app.helper.deepGetter) {
                    return app.helper.deepGetter(key);
                }
                ;
            });
        }
    };
});
System.register("set", [], function (exports_2, context_2) {
    "use strict";
    var set;
    var __moduleName = context_2 && context_2.id;
    return {
        setters: [],
        execute: function () {
            exports_2("set", set = function (key, val) {
                if (app.helper && app.helper.deepSetter) {
                    return app.helper.deepSetter(key, val);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
System.register("helper/deepGetter", [], function (exports_3, context_3) {
    "use strict";
    var deepGetter;
    var __moduleName = context_3 && context_3.id;
    return {
        setters: [],
        execute: function () {
            exports_3("deepGetter", deepGetter = function (key) {
                // get anything
            });
        }
    };
});
System.register("helper/deepSetter", [], function (exports_4, context_4) {
    "use strict";
    var deepSetter;
    var __moduleName = context_4 && context_4.id;
    return {
        setters: [],
        execute: function () {
            exports_4("deepSetter", deepSetter = function (key, val) {
                // set anything
            });
        }
    };
});
System.register("helper/index", ["helper/deepGetter", "helper/deepSetter"], function (exports_5, context_5) {
    "use strict";
    var deepGetter_1, deepSetter_1, helper;
    var __moduleName = context_5 && context_5.id;
    return {
        setters: [
            function (deepGetter_1_1) {
                deepGetter_1 = deepGetter_1_1;
            },
            function (deepSetter_1_1) {
                deepSetter_1 = deepSetter_1_1;
            }
        ],
        execute: function () {
            exports_5("helper", helper = {
                deepGetter: deepGetter_1.deepGetter,
                deepSetter: deepSetter_1.deepSetter,
            });
        }
    };
});
System.register("index", ["get", "set", "helper/index"], function (exports_6, context_6) {
    "use strict";
    var get_1, set_1, index_1, app;
    var __moduleName = context_6 && context_6.id;
    return {
        setters: [
            function (get_1_1) {
                get_1 = get_1_1;
            },
            function (set_1_1) {
                set_1 = set_1_1;
            },
            function (index_1_1) {
                index_1 = index_1_1;
            }
        ],
        execute: function () {
            app = {
                get: get_1.get,
                set: set_1.set,
                helper: index_1.helper,
            };
        }
    };
});
```

I haven't get it working for "--module es2015 --moduleResolution classic",
only for for "--module system --moduleResolution node".
And the file weighs almost six and a half times as much!